# signin from external (but trusted) clients in identity server 4

Tags: identityserver4

I had a requirement that the user could enter his password and username directly on the client to sign on.

Without much trouble i just created a very simple extra authenticate action within the same application as identity server that looks like the following.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUser(
        [FromBody] LoginInputModel model,
        [FromServices] AzureB2CUserService userService
        )
    {
        var context = new ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext { Password = model.Password, UserName = model.Username };

        await userService.ValidateAsync(context);

        if (context.Result.Subject != null)  
        {
            AuthenticationProperties props = null;
            // only set explicit expiration here if persistent. 
            // otherwise we reply upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
            if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
            {
                props = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                };
            };

            // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
            //   var user = _users.FindByUsername(model.Username);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(context.Result.Subject.GetSubjectId(), model.Username, props, context.Result.Subject.Claims.ToArray());

            return Ok(context.Result);

        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);

        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    }
```

from the single page application I then call this action and if success, i know that a local authentication cookie has been for identity server.

Then i do a `.userManager.signinSilent()` from the oidc-client and since the cookie is there, it will get a token exactly the same way if I had used an implicit grant with `userManager.signInRedirect` but without the user getting redirected.

1. Is there something I should be aware of from a security point here. (You may assume that cross site attacks and antiforgery tokens have been handled).
2. instead of callign the silent signin after, could I just do a redirect to the implicit flow in the custom authenticate method and have it end up again with the client application ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I should be aware of from a security point here.
>   (You may assume that cross site attacks and antiforgery tokens have
>   been handled).

My understanding is that you (1) forfeit the ability to participate in Single Sign-on since your browser does not redirect to the SSO Authority, and (2) introduce a weakness in password handling since your client app (both JS/C# in this case) see the password in the plain text.

> instead of callign the silent signin after, could I just do a redirect
>   to the implicit flow in the custom authenticate method and have it end
>   up again with the client application ?

If you did this, then you would essentially have the authorization_code flow without the authorization code. Might as well just upgrade to the higher security of that flow.

Assuming you have a SPA on top of an ASP.NET MVC app, you could use a traditional MVC form post with a redirect to SSO and then, upon return, spin up the SPA.

Comment: "If you did this, then you would essentially have the authorization_code flow without the authorization code. Might as well just upgrade to the higher security of that flow." but that requires that the client have its client secret to change the code, not possible in a public client.

Comment: "Assuming you have a SPA on top of an ASP.NET MVC app, you could use a traditional MVC form post with a redirect to SSO and then, upon return, spin up the SPA." Its extra work, and essential this is exactly what I described I am doing, except the form post endpoint is on the SSO authority app instead of the client app. Now all my trusted clients can do the same without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "My understanding is that you (1) forfeit the ability to participate in Single Sign-on since your browser does not redirect to the SSO Authority, and (2) introduce a weakness in password handling since your client app (both JS/C# in this case) see the password in the plain text." How is a weakness in password handing created? You assume that SSO authority is more secret when it accept your password and does a form post to sign in then my form in the client?